# Modeling of football results

Tags: r, winbugs, jags

I have the attached model (courtesy of Rasmus Bååth) which I am trying to improve to increase my understanding of MCMC and R. Fed into the model is games of football with each row containing (HomeTeam, AwayTeam, Season, HomeGoals, AwayGoals, MatchResult, HomeForm, AwayForm). The model is used for predicting football results in a game between two teams with HomeGoals and AwayGoals modeled as poisson distributions. What I have been trying to accomplish the last few days is to use this data about the current form of the teams in the model but I cannot think of a way to realize it. I am hoping for some suggestions as of how it could be done.

*Some clarifications:*

- Season is the season the game was played in
- MatchResult is -1 if away team wins, 0 if draw, 1 if home team wins.
- HomeForm and AwayForm is a value quantifying the current form of the
  home and away teams respectively (-1 to 1, the rolling average match result of the
  teams last games with a window of five, negative match result if the team played the away side).
- The columns in text are converted to integers before they are passed to the model (factors).

Thank you!

**MODEL:**

```
model {
  for(game_i in 1:n_games) {
    HomeGoals[game_i] ~ dpois(lambda_home[Season[game_i], HomeTeam[game_i], AwayTeam[game_i]])
    AwayGoals[game_i] ~ dpois(lambda_away[Season[game_i], HomeTeam[game_i], AwayTeam[game_i]])
  }

  for(season_i in 1:n_seasons) {
    for(home_i in 1:n_teams) {
      for(away_i in 1:n_teams) {
        lambda_home[season_i, home_i, away_i] <- exp(home_baseline[season_i] + skill[season_i, home_i] - skill[season_i, away_i])
        lambda_away[season_i, home_i, away_i] <- exp(away_baseline[season_i] + skill[season_i, away_i] - skill[season_i, home_i])
      }
    }
  }

  skill[1, 1] <- 0 
  for(j in 2:n_teams) {
    skill[1, j] ~ dnorm(group_skill, group_tau)
  }

  group_skill ~ dnorm(0, 0.0625)
  group_tau <- 1/pow(group_sigma, 2)
  group_sigma ~ dunif(0, 3)

  home_baseline[1] ~ dnorm(0, 0.0625)
  away_baseline[1] ~ dnorm(0, 0.0625)

  for(season_i in 2:n_seasons) {
    skill[season_i, 1] <- 0 
    for(j in 2:n_teams) {
      skill[season_i, j] ~ dnorm(skill[season_i - 1, j], season_tau)
    }
    home_baseline[season_i] ~ dnorm(home_baseline[season_i - 1], season_tau)
    away_baseline[season_i] ~ dnorm(away_baseline[season_i - 1], season_tau)
  }

  season_tau <- 1/pow(season_sigma, 2) 
  season_sigma ~ dunif(0, 3) 
}
```

**DATA (part of):**

```
No. HomeTeam           AwayTeam       Season HomeGoals AwayGoals HomeForm  AwayForm MatchResult
41  Betis              Real Madrid    0809   1         2         -0.6      0.6      -1
42  Espanol            Barcelona      0809   1         2         0.0       0.4      -1
43  Sp Gijon           Villarreal     0809   0         1         -1.0      0.8      -1
44  Almeria            Recreativo     0809   1         0         0.4       -0.4     1
45  Ath Bilbao         Getafe         0809   0         1         -0.2      0.2      -1
46  Ath Madrid         Sevilla        0809   0         1         0.2       0.6      -1
47  Malaga             Valladolid     0809   2         1         -0.4      -0.2     1
48  Numancia           Osasuna        0809   0         0         -0.4      -0.2     0
49  Santander          Mallorca       0809   1         2         -0.6      0.2      -1
50  Valencia           La Coruna      0809   4         2         0.8       -0.2     1
51  Barcelona          Ath Madrid     0809   6         1         0.8      -0.2      1
52  Villarreal         Betis          0809   2         1         1.0      -0.6      1
```

Comment: How do you imagine that `*Form` and `lambda_*` are related in reality?

Comment: So if lambda_* represents the expected number of goals for each side respectively I should add something to it that relates to number of goals somehow. What I could think of was to modify the Form algorithm and instead of using the avg MatchResult one could use the average goal difference for each of the teams.

So, to lambda home is added the average goal difference for the home team minus the average goal difference for the away team, and the other way around for the away teams lambda.

Do you think this is a good idea?

Comment: lambda_home[season_i, home_i, away_i] <- exp(home_baseline[season_i] + skill[season_i, home_i] - skill[season_i, away_i]) + lambda_form_home[season_i,home_i,away_i] - lambda_form_away[season_i,home_i,away_i]

Comment: I won't comment on whether your model is sensible or not, since that's not the purpose of StackOverflow (those questions are more suited to [stats.se]). It might be worth taking a look at some theses/papers that have attempted to model the outcomes of team sports (e.g. [this thesis](http://researchbank.swinburne.edu.au/vital/access/services/Download/swin:6300/SOURCE3)). Predicting sporting outcomes is obviously valuable (e.g. for setting betting odds), so there are plenty of examples out there :)